# Slice strings in a series depending on position of character

Tags: python, pandas

So in my dataframe I want to slice my strings in order to remove a pre-amble from data. The only trouble is that this data is of varying lengths. So I need to work out where it supposed to start.

Before:

```
Day 1 - abc
Day 2 - bcd
DAY 10 - DFE
```

After:

```
abc
bcd
DFE
```

I understand why the following doesn't work but thought I would provide it as a starting point

```
df['String'] = df.String.str.slice(start=df.String.str.find('-')+1)
```

Comment: Why do you think this code doesn't work?

Comment: Don't you want `.find('-')+2` instead of `+1`?  You want to skip the dash and the following space.

Comment: I'm not familiar with dataframes -- why do you use `df['String']` on the left side, and `df.String` on the right?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.split` on each row and split by a `" "`  and then apply a lambda function to retrieve the last element of the list in each row.

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data=["Day 1 - abc", "Day 2 - bcd", "DAY 10 - DFE"], columns=["String"])
df["String"] = df.String.str.split(" ").apply(lambda x: x[-1])
```

**Output:**

```
  String
0    abc
1    bcd
2    DFE
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `.split` instead of `.slice` in order not to worry about the index of the `-`. So something like this is more suitable in my opinion.

```
df['String'] = df.String.str.split(' - ').apply(lambda x: x[-1])
```

*Note*
This method also removes the whitespace around the `-`. If you need the whitespace after the dash on your resulting string you can just remove the whitespace, not the operator like:

```
df['String'] = df.String.str.split('-').apply(lambda x: x[-1])
```

#### Update

After @satilog mentioned in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62009022/6648243) you need to use a lambda to take the last cell from `.split()`. I fixed the code here.

Comment: Are you sure this code works? It didnt work as expected for me when I tried it but instead throws a `KeyError`.

Comment: You are right the lambda you used in your answer is necessary as we are working with df columns! Thanks